# How can we improve the Update / Write operation on BaseX datastore?

Tags: performance, xquery, benchmarking, datastore, basex

I am using BaseX (XML based datastore) for its performance benchmarking. For testing it with ,
TestBeds
I) 10,000 users, 10 friends, 10 resources
II) 100,000 users , 10 friends, 10 resources
I faced below issues:
1) Loading of data is too slow. Gets slowed with eh increase in the number of threads.
2) Plus point - Reading/retriving values from BaseX is faster (17k operation per second)
3) Updating the data in BaseX is very slow. Throughput is ~10 operations per second.

#### Am I correct to say BaseX is 'TOO' slow for write/update operations (20/sec) compared to read/retrieve (10k/sec)?

Please advice me to make it more efficient for the write and update : 
I have a function insertEntity (update or insert function) in to the BaseX datastore as follows -

```
public int insertEntity(String entitySet, String entityPK,
            HashMap<String, ByteIterator> values, boolean insertImage) {

        String parentTag ="",childTag ="", key="", entryTag="";     
        StringBuffer insertData = new StringBuffer();       
        Set<String> keys = values.keySet();
        Iterator<String> iterator = keys.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            String entryKey = iterator.next();
            if(!(entryKey.equalsIgnoreCase("pic") || entryKey.equalsIgnoreCase("tpic")))
                insertData.append("element " + entryKey + " {\"" + StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(values.get(entryKey).toString()) + "\"},");      
        }   

        if(entitySet.equalsIgnoreCase("users")&& insertImage){
            byte[] profileImage = ((ObjectByteIterator)values.get("pic")).toArray();
            String encodedpImage = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(profileImage);
            insertData.append(" element pic {\"" + encodedpImage + "\"},");

            profileImage = ((ObjectByteIterator)values.get("tpic")).toArray();
            encodedpImage = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(profileImage);
            insertData.append(" element tpic {\"" + encodedpImage + "\"},");
        }

        if(entitySet.equalsIgnoreCase("users"))
        {   
                parentTag = "users";
                childTag = "members";
                entryTag = "member";
                key = "mem_id"; 
                insertData.append("element confirmed_friends {}, element pending_friends {}");

        }
        if(entitySet.equalsIgnoreCase("resources"))
        {   
                parentTag = "resources";
                childTag = "resources";
                entryTag = "resource";
                key = "rid";
                insertData.append("element manipulations {}");
        }


        try {
            session.execute(new XQuery(
                    "insert node element " + entryTag
                      + "{ attribute " + key + "{"
                      + entityPK + "}, "
                      + insertData.toString()
                      + "} "
                      + "into doc('" + databaseName + "/" + parentTag +".xml')/" + childTag
                ));

            String q1 = "insert node element " + entryTag
                      + "{ attribute " + key + "{"
                      + entityPK + "}, "
                      + insertData.toString()
                      + "} "
                      + "into doc('" + databaseName + "/" + parentTag +".xml')/" + childTag;
            System.out.println(q1);




        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

And the below function is acceptFriendship (update function)

```
public int acceptFriend(int inviterID, int inviteeID) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String acceptFriendQuery1 = "insert node <confirmed_friend id = '"
                + inviterID + "'>"
                + " </confirmed_friend>"
                + "into doc('"+databaseName+"/users.xml')/members/member[@mem_id = '"+inviteeID+"']/confirmed_friends";

        String acceptFriendQuery2 = "insert node <confirmed_friend id = '"
                + inviteeID + "'>"
                + " </confirmed_friend>"
                + "into doc('"+databaseName+"/users.xml')/members/member[@mem_id = '"+inviterID+"']/confirmed_friends";

        String acceptFriendQuery3 = "delete node doc('"+databaseName+"/users.xml')/members/member[@mem_id = '"
                + inviteeID + "']/pending_friends/pending_friend[@id = '"+ inviterID +"']";

        try {

            session.execute(new XQuery(acceptFriendQuery1));
            session.execute(new XQuery(acceptFriendQuery2));
            session.execute(new XQuery(acceptFriendQuery3));

            System.out.println("Inviter: "+inviterID +" AND Invitee: "+inviteeID);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Is your benchmark suite public? Perhaps on GitHub somewhere? I would be interested in testing this against eXist-db for comparison.

Comment: I don't think your question is a good fit for SO - You might be better off asking at our BaseX mailing list. Many of the issues you face are quite logical (e.g. having more threads when your operation is IO bound is quite logical, because the disk always has to switch between storage locations), others are just not that simple (fast update operations).